# Salesforce Post API integration giving error {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"} in PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, postman, salesforce

The integration of a Salesforce API POST request in PHP cURL is resulting in an error message:

> {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}.

This error is caused by the Follow Authorization header setting in POSTMAN. Even when this setting is disabled in POSTMAN, the same error persists. I would like to understand how to correctly implement the PHP cURL code to handle the Follow Authorization header setting in POSTMAN.

Code

```
$bearerToken = 'BEARER_TOKEN';

    $apiEndpoint = 'URL/services/data/v56.0/composite/graph';

    // Sample POST data
    $postData = [
        "graphs" => [
            [
                "graphId" => 1,
                "compositeRequest" => [
                    [
                        "method" => "POST",
                        "url" => "/services/data/v56.0/.....",
                        "referenceId" => "...",
                        "body" => [
                            "dmpl__AccountId__c" => "0010p00001IcijMAAR"                        
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    // Convert POST data to JSON
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $apiEndpoint,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
//        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonData,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $bearerToken,
            'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
        ),
    ));

    // Send the POST request
    $postResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        // HTTP status code
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        // Check response status code
        if ($statusCode == 200) {
            echo 'POST request successful';
            echo $postResponse;
        } else {
            echo 'POST request failed with status code ' . $statusCode;
            echo $postResponse;
        }
    }
```

I attempted various header options in my endeavors, exploring the creation of tokens directly from Salesforce and subsequently passing them in the code.

Comment: How are you generating the session id (authorization bearer ... part). Logging in with postman/PHP too? Maybe your admin clicked "limit sessions to IP from which they originated", that's why you can't simply "steal" session id created in another program. And Like ghtning Experience's sessions ar not API enabled so no point stealing them from say a cookie...

Comment: _"This error is caused by the Follow Authorization header setting in POSTMAN. Even when this setting is disabled in POSTMAN, the same error persists."_ - so you get the error, regardless of whether you turn that option on or off? Then I don't see how it could be _caused_ by that?

Comment: @eyescream Thank you for your prompt reply. We are generating a session ID using the login API.$loginEndpoint = 'URL.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

// Set cURL options for login API request
$loginData = array(
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
);

Comment: @cbroee I would like to understand how we can set up this (Follow Authorization header: ON) configuration using PHP cURL.

Comment: and "api endpoint"? Do you also read that from the login's response (instance_url field)?

Comment: @eyescream Yes reading this from instance_url field